# CONCAT but if already done, ignore

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I would like to add an asterisk (*) after a person's name if a piece of information about the profile is outdated.

Donald

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE contacts SET name = concat(name, '*') WHERE phone = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$phone);
$stmt->execute();
```

Donald*

This works fine the first time but if nothing has changed and I update the profile, it adds another asterisk so then the name is
Donald**. Next time it is Donald*** etc.

What would be the solution to check if the name already has an asterisk and if so, do nothing?

Comment: Unless determining something is outdated is quite expensive, this seems like it would be better handled just as formatting on the client side based on outdated status. If in this scenario you're thinking "someone tried calling the number and it was disconnected", how is that * going to indicate the phone number is the outdated piece, and not something else like a mailing address a letter or package was returned from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `right()` to check if the last character is a `*` and only update rows where this is not the case.

```
UPDATE contacts
       SET name = concat(name, '*')
       WHERE phone = ?
             AND right(name, 1) <> '*';
```

Comment: I haven't even came across that function before but looks like I should take a look. It seems to do the job as I wanted. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a conditional test in the expression that derives the new value. e.g.

```
UPDATE contacts
   SET name = CONCAT(name, CASE 
                             WHEN name LIKE '%*' THEN ''
                             ELSE '*'
                           END
              )     
 WHERE phone = ?
```